# How can I extract unique strings from a Dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I have a dataframe 'df_copy' which has a column 'genres'. In the column, each entry has single or multiple genres. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sftTC.jpg)

I wish to extract all the unique genres that are present in the column.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_df = df_copy['genres'].str.split(',',expand = True)
```